# Git merge branches with renamed files

Tags: git, git-merge, file-rename

We have two branches one main and other development.
We do our changes on the development branch and periodically merge it with main.
In my recent changes I did some file renames in the development branch and committed these (using mv file_old file_new then git add) , and git picked it up as rename as well.
Now while merging the development branch to main (using git merge development --no --ff) , I see that the main branch has both the files renamed one and older one as well.

Is there a better way we can just have the newer file (renamed one) without having the older one after merging ?

DEVELOPMENT BRANCH

```bash
mv file_old file_new
git add .
git commit
```

MAIN BRANCH

```
git merge development
```

Comment: there's no merge conflict , I simply see both the files present in main branch after merging

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally with git when using `ort` merging strategy

Comment: You must have done something else that you did not tell us, because normally `git merge` would either have picked up the rename without complaint or it would have generated a merge conflict.

Comment: I find the description fishy. In my experience, if there is _no_ conflict if a file has been moved, you might either get the movement correctly detected and the file would be them moved _during merge time_... or you would get a deletion if the file content has changed that much in the branch where it was moved that git is not able to detect that it was actually moved (during _merge time_).

Comment: Can you add to the question the following command output?  `git diff --name-status branch1...branch2 -- the-original-file` and `git diff --name-status branch2...branch1 -- the-original-file` (notice it's triple dot `...` not double dot `..`).

Comment: Also: `git ls-tree $( git merge-base branch1 branch2 ) -- the-original-file the-final-file`, `git ls-tree branch1 -- the-original-file the-final-file`, `git ls-tree branch2 -- the-original-file the-final-file`.